# Extend GUI on 2 monitors using MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, mfc

I have three monitors with different screen size. I am write a GUI using MFC in C++ to extend the GUI to 2 monitors from 3 monitors. That means I have 3 monitors but GUI only display in 2 monitors, the remaining monitor is used for other task. Is it possible in MFC? Could you suggest me the way to do it. Currently, I tried with below code and [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145072(v=vs.85).aspx) . But it display GUI in all monitors(3 monitors).

```
CRect rcDesktop;
rcDesktop.left = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.right = rcDesktop.left + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.top = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
rcDesktop.bottom = rcDesktop.top + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
MoveWindow(rcDesktop, FALSE);
```

I also done for single monitor as

```
SetParent(GetDesktopWindow());
CRect rect;
GetDesktopWindow()->GetWindowRect(&rect);
SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost,rect.left,rect.top,rect.right,rect.bottom,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

The goal is 
[image]
Thank for your help

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to just multiply the width by two thirds.

Comment: Actually, I have 3 monitor with difference screen size. I don't know multiple is possible solution

Comment: My idea is that I will determine the primary screen and put the other task in it. The remaining screens will display the GUI. Is it possible

Answer (score 1):

Use [EnumDisplayMonitors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the metrics for all of the monitors attached to the machine, and add up the sizes for the two on the left.

You'll need to make some assumptions and/or additional calculations about monitor geometry and how they're arranged with respect to each other. For example, the leftmost two are not necessarily the first two in the enumeration order. But that should get you the data you need to do it.

Comment: Good suggestion. Could you provide the code to me? Thanks

Comment: Nope. That's your job. :) Post again if you get stuck and have specific questions on it.